# setText doesn't set text

Tags: android, settext

I have a class that fetches som data from a website. I've followed [TheNewBoston's tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6) (147-149 I think) and copied what he writes *exactly*, but it doesn't work for me. The problem is the `setText`. I try to switch `tv.setText(returned)` to `tv.setText("Hello")`  but it doesn't change. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
    String returned;

    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        tv.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you before debug what've you get in `returned` and, Have you got any exception? Otherwise, please provide some more code here.

Comment: If `getInternetData()` throws an exception, you never get to the `setText()` call, and as it won't work even when you use "hello" as the argument, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Please show the exception what you are getting from test.getInternetData(). May be we can then get exact problem and its solution. I think you are using another thread to call server and then setting that value to textview so it gives and exception. Please update your question with exception log

Comment: Lol, i saw that the class wasn't even the launcher class. Changed it in the manifest and now it works just fine. But thank you all anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
  try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        tv.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

by

```
  try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        tv.setText("returned");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
```

setText will then set Text as you requested!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String returned = "some default string.";
try {
    returned = test.getInternetData();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
tv.setText(returned);
```

This way, you know that setText will be called with data, regardless of if there was an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {

                tv.setText(returned.toString());

                }
            });
```